# dbf to csv using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, dbf

Hi Can any one help me to convert dbf files(placed in storage account) to csv using azure batch accounts using azure data factory custom activity. Kindly provide the python code

I created a batch account and tried executing python file which is placed in storage account using azure data factory custom activity using below code. It is showing executed succesfully but csv file not found under storage account.

```
import csv
from dbfread import DBF, FieldParser
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

# Replace these with your actual Azure Storage account information
account_name = "my_account_name"
account_key = "my_account_key"
container_name = "dbf"
blob_name = "test.dbf"

# Connection string for Azure Blob Storage
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# Download the DBF file from Azure Blob Storage
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
downloaded_file = "downloaded_file.dbf"

try:
    with open(downloaded_file, "wb") as download_file:
        download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error downloading DBF file: {e}")
    exit()

# Convert DBF to CSV
class CustomFieldParser(FieldParser):
    def _parse_memo_index(self, data):
        try:
            return int(data)
        except ValueError:
            return data.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')

try:
    dbf_file = DBF(downloaded_file, parserclass=CustomFieldParser)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error reading DBF file: {e}")
    exit()

csv_file = "converted_file.csv"

try:
    with open(csv_file, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        # Write header
        writer.writerow(dbf_file.field_names)

        # Write rows
        for record in dbf_file:
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))

    print(f"Conversion completed. CSV file saved as {csv_file}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error writing CSV file: {e}")
```

Comment: Can you provide your pipeline JSON and custom activity configurations for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided converts a DBF file into a CSV file in the local path. You did not mention the path where the CSV file needs to be stored, so the CSV file is being stored in the path where the DBF file was downloaded. This may be the reason the pipeline is successful, but the CSV file is not in the storage account. Mention the blob storage account path for the CSV file using the code below:

```py
# Convert to CSV
csv_data = []
csv_data.append(dbf_file.field_names)  # Add header

for record in dbf_file:
    csv_data.append(list(record.values()))

# Convert CSV data to string
csv_string = '\n'.join([','.join(map(str, row)) for row in csv_data])

# Upload CSV data to blob
try:
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=cblob_name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(csv_string, overwrite=True)

    print(f"Conversion completed. CSV file saved as {cblob_name} in container {container_name}")
```

This will successfully convert the DBF file into a CSV file and store it in the storage account as shown below:

[image]

Here is the complete code for your reference:

```py
import csv
import sys
from dbfread import DBF, FieldParser
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

# Replace these with your actual Azure Storage account information
account_name = "bhanustoree"
account_key = "HraF6Fn5pn5DaMN1opUzX7oq2t5b0SSHcaaR2+SS5aabGsWCC5DsBTE7tfIvHGRau4ptpqB9oQTi+ASty3JSYA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
container_name = "files"
blob_name = 'marks.dbf'
cblob_name = "converted_file.csv"  # Name of the blob where you want to save the CSV file
# Connection string for Azure Blob Storage
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
# Download the DBF file from Azure Blob Storage
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
downloaded_file = "downloaded1_file.dbf"

try:
    with open(downloaded_file, "wb") as download_file:
        download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error downloading DBF file: {e}")
    sys.exit()

# Convert DBF to CSV
class CustomFieldParser(FieldParser):
    def _parse_memo_index(self, data):
        try:
            return int(data)
        except ValueError:
            return data.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')

try:
    dbf_file = DBF(downloaded_file, parserclass=CustomFieldParser)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error reading DBF file: {e}")
    sys.exit()

# Convert to CSV
csv_data = []
csv_data.append(dbf_file.field_names)  # Add header

for record in dbf_file:
    csv_data.append(list(record.values()))

# Convert CSV data to string
csv_string = '\n'.join([','.join(map(str, row)) for row in csv_data])

# Upload CSV data to blob
try:
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=cblob_name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(csv_string, overwrite=True)

    print(f"Conversion completed. CSV file saved as {cblob_name} in container {container_name}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error uploading CSV file to blob storage: {e}")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Code is working fine.

Comment: I am getting the below error:

Error reading DBF file: missing memo file for downloaded1_file.dbf

Comment: Use anthore db file like [this](https://github.com/nagasudhirpulla/taming_python/raw/master/blog/skills/assets/data/marks.dbf), it will work without any error.

Comment: In my case few dbf file contains(*.fpt) memo files along with dbf and few don't have memo file. Your code is working which dont have any memo file but failing for the once which have memo file.  
Please refer below link:
https://file.io/EFXQMaw2S3py

Comment: Can we skip this error and proceed with csv conversion without considering memo file? In online dbf to csv conversion tools its working without memo file.

Comment: could you please help me in this regard?